# Powershell Script in SSIS - Failure to load assembly

Tags: powershell, ssis

I need to run a PowerShell script from within an SSIS package using a Process Task:

```
try {
    Import-Module X -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Output ($_.Exception.ItemName + " - " + $_.Exception.Message)
    exit 99
}
```

Encountering the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'X.dll' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Exact same script runs fine directly on Powershell.

Comment: Can you import the module outside of SSIS?

Comment: Yes, exact same script works if I run it directly on PowerShell.

Comment: Well, then there is something that the SSIS environment doesn't have that Module X needs. Sonds like a question for the people that make module X.